# QGIS2web page does not display curved labels

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have designed a non-real map, using QGIS. Until now, my map was very basic (a few layers with some polygons, dots, and lines). This map is a "decal" from a raster image.

I recently add some custom labels, which are displayed into a certain zoom range, and also some labels (using invisible dots or lines, if I need curved labels).

**Here is how a part of my map looks in QGIS :**

[image]

**Here is what the qgis2web export give me for the same area :**

[image]

How can I export the map to the web in the most accurate way possible?

Comment: to preserve curved labels you will need to generate tiles http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quantumnik/ will create tiles in QGIS

Comment: Of course, that's the other way to do it as @Mapperz says - a raster layer, tiled or untiled.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I can't find the plugin in QGIS although it's available on the previous link.

Comment: you can copy the files from github and load locally (into C:\Users\user\.qgis2\python\plugins\quantumnik) you might have to restart QGIS to have it picked up.

Comment: @TomChadwin I have the same problem. please if you can in the new version of the plug in create the possibility, that the line names can be placed parallel to the lines.
because we need it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid I don't think this is possible either with OL3's labels or with the Leaflet label plugin. I therefore don't think curved labels can be easily developed in qgis2web. They're certainly not currently possible, I'm afraid. If someone knows how to do them in either mapping lib, please let us know.